# Git - rolling back to a previous commit without losing work

Tags: git, merge, branch

I had previously been working on features and merging them into a master branch only. Now, i need to maintain master as a stable-feature-only branch and then work on a dev branch to build new features.

The problem is that I'm ahead of my target stable commit on master.

I'd like to set master to say, 5 commits ago, push that branch up, and then maintain that as a stable branch for deploying to my production server.

This is what I've done so far:
On latest commit (ahead of my stable commit), I created a new branch "dev"
Now dev will be my unstable, new feature build.

Now I'm sitting with master and dev at the same (unstable) commit.

What I'd like is for master to now be sitting at my previous stable commit (5 commits ago).

Bonus question - if I then want to add in features from dev (which will be x commits ahead of master), but only after they are stable, is that possible? 
Let's say I'm on dev and I've built an activity feed and an email system and I'd like to only include the email system.

How do I merge my email system feature branch into master (5 commits behind dev, which email-system branch is based off of) without introducing all my other changes (changes made in those 5 commits that dev is ahead of master)?

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: What have you pushed already?  It's very easy (git checkout master; git reset --hard <commit id>) to move your local master back where you want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To undo commits:

```
git reset HEAD~5 --hard # 5 being number of commits, --hard to not keep around changed files
```

Since you branched from master, the commit history is still there in dev. Merge back into master once it's ready.

As for your bonus question, this is usually done with feature branches. For example, I usually have several branches I'm working on: master (only stable code here), 1.x (only released code here), feature-X, feature-Y, etc.

Each feature is sandboxed, so when it's ready, I just merge that into master. If a feature Y depends on X, I merge X into Y and keep working. Once one's done, merge to master, test and push.

There's a good write-up on this style of development: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/. This post introduces `git-flow`, which is pretty popular. I don't use it exactly as written, but I've taken a fair bit of advice from it.

You could alternatively rebase against master, excluding commits you don't want to keep. For that, I would use `git rebase -i master` (-i being interactive). This will let you look at and manipulate commits before you merge into master. I recommend branching before you do this to prevent breaking your branch.

Comment: Just to be extra clear (as losing those 5 commits by doing a hard reset would be very bad), a hard reset on master WILL NOT do anything to my dev branch?

Comment: Exactly. If you're paranoid, do it on a test branch first. It won't mess up your remote branch unless you push.

Comment: Also, thanks for adding in the link to git-flow. I read it when I first started using git, but now that I've been using it for a while I believe I'm actually ready to start using it.

Answer (score 2):

do this to maintain a pointer to your current master

```
git branch -m master old_master
```

then

```
git checkout -b master HEAD~5
```

to move tour master 5 commits ago (or specify a sha), then you could remove old_master with

```
git branch -d old_master
```

For the bonus question, you could develop features branches and merge them with --no-ff in development branch, then sitting on master you would do git merge --no-ff devcommit , where devcommit represent a merge of that feature branch in development.

You could see in [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) post an example on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

On your branch master:

- `git checkout -b dev` : you now have a dev branch pointing to same hash as master (unstable)
- `git reset --hard HEAD~5` : master is now 5 commits ago (your unstable commits are still on your branch)

Bonus :

- look for `git cherry-pick`
- build your "e-mail" feature on a branch from dev and then `rebase` your branch e-mail on `master` (on e-mail branch : `git rebase master`)